# TRI Import.ps1 fails for websites-only

Tags: 2013-sp1, powershell, dxa

I am trying to import the SDL Tridion Reference Implementation using the supplied import.ps1 power-shell script but getting the following error indicating something amiss with default templates.

I've tried with

```
.\import.ps1 -cmsUrl "http://cms.tri.com/" -importType "all-publications"
```

and

```
.\import.ps1 -cmsUrl "http://cms.tri.com/" -importType "website-only"
```

I did note that the documentation states to create **000 Empty Master** when the content port packages expect **000 Empty** - needless to say I've got both whilst I try to get this to work!

> Problem importing file all-publications.zip Import process
>   '35a4659d65144304a6a8028b904d4099' is started by
>   'TRAIN1\Administrator'. Import started at 5/1/2015 12:26:57 AM.
>   Building list of items to import and determining required import
>   actions. Unzipping and initializing package for import. Import of
>   system administration items started at 5/1/2015 12:27:01 AM. Import
>   items into publication '000 Empty' started at 5/1/2015 12:27:01 AM.
>   Import items into publication '100 Master' started at 5/1/2015
>   12:27:07 AM. Import items into publication '400 Example Site' started
>   at 5/1/2015 12:27:19 AM.
>   Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidPropertyValueException: Invalid value
>   for property 'DefaultPageTemplate'. Default PageTemplate property
>   mustn't be set if IsDefaultPageTemplateInherited property is true.
>   at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.StructureGroup.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs
>   eventArgs)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs
>   eventArgs)    at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
>   at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__1(Boolean
>   isRetry)    atdd
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func'2
>   function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean
>   isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.InvokeInErrorHandler[T](Func'2
>   function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean
>   isCritical)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject
>   item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaObject)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CreateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData
>   itemData)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl
>   exportUrl, IList'1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary'2
>   unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1
>   items, Boolean specialGroupImport)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String
>   packageName) Transactional import failed at 5/1/2015 12:27:21 AM. No
>   changes were committed to Tridion Content Manager. Import process
>   '35a4659d65144304a6a8028b904d4099' is finished. At
>   D:\triinstall\import\import.ps1:317 char:9
>   +         throw "Problem importing file $($filename)$($extension) $($impexp.GetPro ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I've removed any `Inherit from Parent` checked values on the `Page Template` in case this was affecting it.

I did manage to import the 100 Master.

I've also confirmed that I'm able to manually create a dummy page in the 400 Example Site Publication.

### Update

I've run with debug on and can see this fails at:

> 2015/05/01 00:42:59 <72> [Debug] Going to save item tcm:0-0-0 with
>   data:

```
<tcm:StructureGroup xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" IsEditable="true">
    <tcm:Data>
        <tcm:Title>010 Articles</tcm:Title>
        <tcm:DefaultPageTemplate IsInherited="true" xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="" xlink:href="/webdav/400%20Example%20Site/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Editor/Templates/Content%20Page.tptcmp" />
        <tcm:Directory IsMandatory="true">articles</tcm:Directory>
        <tcm:IsActive ResolvedValue="true">true</tcm:IsActive>
        <tcm:PageProcess xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="" xlink:href="tcm:0-0-0" />
        <tcm:PageBundleProcess xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="" xlink:href="tcm:0-0-0" />
        <tcm:MetadataSchema xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="" xlink:href="tcm:0-0-0" />
        <tcm:Metadata />
    </tcm:Data>
</tcm:StructureGroup>
```

> 2015/05/01 00:42:59 <72> [Debug] Unable to save item
>   '/webdav/400%20Example%20Site/Home/010%20Articles' to TCM. The pro
>   cess will be aborted.

To this end I've ensure that

```
/webdav/400%20Example%20Site/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Editor/Templates/Content%20Page.tptcmp
```

1. exists
2. that I am able to create a page with the same
3. I can set a SG manually with this as the degault
4. I can create a page with this set as default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I delved a little further a followed what the code was doing.

The devil was in the detail

```
<tcm:DefaultPageTemplate IsInherited="true" blah blah blah />
```

So as I'd implemented this into an existing Blueprint for testing I'd neglected to consider that the SG 'Home' was created above the `100 Master` and therefore didn't have access to the necessary Page Template to be set so it could inherit.

**Solution:**
Localize `Home` at the `100 Master` and set the `Default Page Template` to `Content`.

Tested I could then do this manually at the 400 Example Website level and executed the script again.

***BOOM***. Success.

Now looking forward to some real fun.

### Note on the setup

Note also that the documentation does assume this is on a clean install - which MINE WASN'T ... so most of this pain could be considered self-inflicted but I hope it's still usefull to those that want to have it as part of a wider sales pitch-set etc.