# Problem installing DXA 1.2 Java into Content Manager

Tags: content-manager, dxa, dxa-java

I am trying to run the import.ps1 script which ships with the DXA 1.2 Java version and have an issue.

The Powershell script is unable to complete the import successfully and is giving the following error:

> FullyQualifiedErrorId : Problem importing file all-publications.zip Import process 'b544b9736ed84299815231d075b1d3e6'
>   is started by 'TRAIN1\Adminstrator'. Import started at 1/18/2016
>   8:42:17 PM. Building list of items t
>        o import and determining required import actions. Unzipping and initializi
>       ng package for import. Import of system administration items started at 1/
>       18/2016 8:42:19 PM. Import items into publication '000 Empty' started at 1
>       /18/2016 8:42:19 PM. Import items into publication '100 Master' started at
>       1/18/2016 8:42:23 PM. Tridion.ContentManager.FilterException: The Filter
>       condition 'ForRepository' is invalid. The item tcm:0-18-1 does not exist.

Sorry for the formatting this is pasted from Powershell.

It looks to me like it's unable to use the Ids of the newly created Publications to perform the import of items...

I have tried various different commands.

I guess my next step is to try creating the blueprint myself first and then importing into that?

Any hints?

I'm sure I didn't hit this issue when trying out the .NET version.

**Further update:**

I have tried creating a BluePrint which matches the DXA created one to see if that helps but I now get the following error:

> Problem importing file all-publications.zip Import process
>   'eeaa0a73acf349778dae3f5ce50d5428' is started by
>   'TRAIN1\Administrator'. Import started at 1/19/2016 11:14:51 AM.
>   Building list of items to import and determining required import
>   actions. Unzipping and initializing package for import. Import of
>   system administration items started at 1/19/2016 11:14:55 AM. Import
>   items into publication '000 Empty' started at 1/19/2016 11:14:55 AM.
>   Import items into publication '100 Master' started at 1/19/2016
>   11:14:55 AM. Import items into publication '400 Example Site' started
>   at 1/19/2016 11:15:10 AM.
>   Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidPropertyValueException: Invalid value
>   for property 'DefaultPageTemplate'. Default PageTemplate property
>   mustn't be set if IsDefaultPageTemplateInherited property is true.

Am I missing a hotfix?

I don't see anything on http://community.sdl.com or http://www.sdltridionworld.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

> Tridion.ContentManager.FilterException: The Filter condition 'ForRepository' is invalid. The item tcm:0-18-1 does not exist.

Is actually mentioned in the known issues in the documentation: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v2/GUID-12814F63-48F0-452F-BE31-A7601F9DA56A

It is related to having ECL installed on your CMS, nothing to do with the .NET or Java version, since the exports of both are exactly the same (there are no CMS differences for DXA). The solution is also mentiond in the documentation, disable the ECL event handler before the import, and re-enable again after the import.

Answer (score 3):

Following Mark's lead here: [TRI Import.ps1 fails for websites-only](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11732/tri-import-ps1-fails-for-websites-only)

I ran "master-only" and then localized my Home structure group. Then I ran with "website-only" and now everything looks good.

So to clarify, I needed to create my own Blueprint, including adding a "Home" Structure Group to 000 Empty before adding the other publications.

- 000 Empty
- 100 Master
- 400 Example Site

Then import master-only, then localize the Home Structure Group at 400 example site, uncheck inherit from parent and set the Default Page Template to Content Page.

Hope this helps someone else.